# Error when using substr limit text with format html?

Tags: php

```
$text = '<p>Download game <a href="">Avatar</a> for <b>Iphone 3GS</b></p>';
<?php 
echo strip_tags(substr($text, 0, 10))." ..."; 
?>
```

But resut is `...`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Place your `$text` definition within `<?php ?>` tags. Otherwise, PHP treats it as plain output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
  $text = '<p>Download game <a href="">Avatar</a> for <b>Iphone 3GS</b></p>';
  echo strip_tags(substr($text, 0, 10))." ..."; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out the $text variable declaration needs to be within the PHP section.

Also I'd suggest that you strip_tags first and then substr the result as otherwise strip_tags won't be able to remove all of the tags.

i.e:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Download game <a href="">Avatar</a> for <b>Iphone 3GS</b></p>';
echo substr(strip_tags($text), 0, 10)." ...";
```

and even possibly as follows: so you'd get `Download game Avatar ...Iphone 3GS`

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Download game <a href="">Avatar</a> for <b>Iphone 3GS</b></p>';
$ntext = strip_tags($text);
echo substr($ntext, 0, 20). 
     (strlen($ntext) > 20 ? "...".substr($ntext, min(20,strlen($ntext)-10)):"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with:

```
<?php

 $text = '<p>Download game <a href="">Avatar</a> for <b>Iphone 3GS</b></p>';
 echo strip_tags(substr($text, 0, 10))." ...";

?>
```

And the output was `Downloa ...`

What do you expect to be shown?